# "IF" Statement Help

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I've asked this over at Stack Overflow (believing it to be a replacement for Experts Exchange), but it seems to be mainly for software developers:

This is probably a simple one for some you you wizz kids. I have an O365 Sharepoint Site with a form in which a school is using to collate pupil scores.

We have 3 cells which have numeric values as follows:

```
Column A: Number 
Column B: Number 
Column C: Number 
Column D: Calculated: Column C - Column A
```

What we need to do is to make column D display conditional data based on 2 scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

If Column C has no data in it = Column B - Column A.

**Scenario 2:**

If Column C does have data in it = Column C - Column A

How would I write out the calculation?

Comment: Do columns A, B, and C have default values configured?

Answer (score 1):

[Examples of common formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

You can use almost the same formula's as in Excel.

To check if column C is empty use

```
=ISBLANK( [Column C] )
```

The whole formula could be someting like

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column C]), [Column B] - [Column A], [Column C] - [Column A] )
```